# Criar super usuário dentro de um container docker que esta sento utilizado com compose

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, docker

Tenho um projeto django que está rodando com docker-compose, oque eu preciso fazer e muito simples, rodar python manage.py createsuperuser, porém, mesmo setando o comando via dockerfile ou no .yml do compose não consigo criar esse super usuário, alguém sabe o processo que deve ser feito para se ter êxito no que estou tentando fazer?

Comment: Talvez este link ajude: https://realpython.com/blog/python/django-development-with-docker-compose-and-machine/

Comment: consegui resolver o problema, simplesmente deve-se utilizar: docker-compose run --rm api bash -c "python manage.py createsuperuser" , tendo em mente que api e minha variável backend no docker-compose.